# Leaflet Plugin: how to make circle marker draggable on touch screens too?

Tags: events, leaflet, touch

please take a look at my measurement-plugin for Leaflet: [Leaflet.PolylineMeasure](https://ppete2.github.io/Leaflet.PolylineMeasure/test4.html)
You can view the plugin's [javascript code](https://github.com/ppete2/Leaflet.PolylineMeasure/blob/master/Leaflet.PolylineMeasureTest4.js) on my Github site.

It's working perfect on **desktop browsers**.

Even on **touch devices** it's possible to draw the measure points and end a line by clicking onto the last point (or switching the measure button off). But it's **not possible to move the points** afterwords and correct their position on the map. I tried using parallel event definitions of mouse events and touch events, but the moving on touch devices doesn't work

```
self._map.on ('mousemove touchmove', function (e2) {
```

Does anybody has an idea what to change?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?